# Empty Json received in DynamoDBMapper unconvert method

Tags: java, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have json data in aws dynamoDB wherein there is a field with nested json. I wanted to get that nested json in a Java HashMap. To achieve this, I have written a custom converter in a class implementing DynamoDBTypeConverter.

Here is my JSON data -

```
{
    "id": "1234",
    "payment": {
        "payment_id": "2345",
        "user_defined": {
            "some_id": "3456"
            }
        }
}
```

I wanted to map `user_defined` to a Java HasMap.

This is my converter class -

```
public class HashMapConverter implements DynamoDBTypeConverter<String, customHashMap<String, Object>> {

    @Override
    public String convert(customHashMap<String, Object> hashMap) {
        System.out.println("userDefined is " + hashMap);
        System.out.println("Converting userDefined to string");
        return "Akshansh";
        //return new Gson().toJson(hashMap);
    }

    @Override
    public customHashMap<String, Object> unconvert(String jsonString) {
        System.out.println("jsonString received for unconverting is " + jsonString);
        System.out.println("Unconverting attribute");

        return new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, new TypeToken<customHashMap<String, Object>>(){}.getType());
    }
}
```

My problem is that in the `unconvert` method of the above converter, I'm receiving an empty string even though my data clearly contains information in the `user_defined` field.

Any help with this problem will be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have done a similar thing taking field types as `Object`.

```
public class ObjectConverter implements DynamoDBTypeConverter<Map<String, AttributeValue>, Object> {

    @Override
    public Map<String, AttributeValue> convert(Object object) {
        Item item = new Item().withJSON("object", InternalUtils.valToString(object));
        Map<String, AttributeValue> attributes = InternalUtils.toAttributeValues(item);
        return attributes.get("object").getM();
    }

    @Override
    public Object unconvert(Map<String, AttributeValue> attributes) {
        List<Map<String, AttributeValue>> mapList = new ArrayList<>();
        mapList.add(attributes);
        return new Gson().toJson(InternalUtils.toItemList(mapList).get(0).asMap());
    }
}
```